# how to export pdf to another pdf without images

Tags: php, image, pdf, command-line

i'm develop a php application and i need to save a pdf to another pdf but without the images. I need only text of my original pfd. is Possible to do it in php on linux server? I try with pdfbox, but is impossible do it with command line. There are other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want text reflow, [cpdf](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/indexse52.html#x70-8100015.1) is free for non-commercial use.